# Bootstrap custom carousel with css only

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to make some effect with css only to extend Bootstrap, it does work properly, but but only when the click happens in the right arrow, but when is in the left one, it just do nothing... maybe I miss spell something, but i cant see it... thanks in advance :)

```
#sigle-items-slider .item {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.765, 0.185, 0.000, 0.730);
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.765, 0.185, 0.000, 0.730);
    -ms-transition: opacity 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.765, 0.185, 0.000, 0.730);
    -o-transition: opacity 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.765, 0.185, 0.000, 0.730);
    transition: opacity 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.765, 0.185, 0.000, 0.730);
}

#sigle-items-slider .active.left {
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    z-index:2;
}

#sigle-items-slider .active.right {
    right:0;
    opacity:0;
    z-index:2;
}
#sigle-items-slider .next {
    left:0;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:1;
}

#sigle-items-slider .prev {
    left:0;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:1;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry it took a time, here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uDvBL/)

Comment: Could you post a fiddle or something so we can get a better idea of the project?

Comment: What is the effect you're intending to achieve? It seems like you want a fade in / out? Try looking at your z-index entries, that may be the cause of your issue.

Comment: if you click to right side you can see it.. but you click to the left it doesnt get trigger.. what you mean z-index entries? looks fine to me... @badAdviceGuy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing on the wrong selector:

http://jsfiddle.net/uDvBL/2/

```
$("#sigle-items-slider").carousel({
    interval: 1000
})

#sigle-items-slider .item {
    left: 0 !important;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.765, 0.185, 0.000, 0.730);
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.765, 0.185, 0.000, 0.730);
    -ms-transition: opacity 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.765, 0.185, 0.000, 0.730);
    -o-transition: opacity 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.765, 0.185, 0.000, 0.730);
    transition: opacity 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.765, 0.185, 0.000, 0.730);
}

#sigle-items-slider .active.left {
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    z-index:2;
}

#sigle-items-slider .active.right {
    right:0;
    opacity:0;
    z-index:2;
}
#sigle-items-slider .next {
    left:0;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:1;
}

#sigle-items-slider .prev {
    left:0;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but that doesnt fix the main problem.. which is the `transition ` effect

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. I updated my answer with a slight adjustment to your css and it works both ways.

Comment: Added left: 0 !important; to the first selector.